# Issues with Network interface card in CentOS 7

Tags: linux, networking, centos

I have just installed centOS in machine having 4 NICs. CentOS detected 2 of them but two or them are still missing from network manager. Both two of them are of same kind, I suspect that it's a driver that is causing me problem...

When i use lspci it displays those two card but they wont work.

Here if ouput of  lspci | grep -i 'ethernet':

```
root@System911 ~]# lspci | grep -i 'ethernet'
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82566DM-2 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 02)
07:04.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82557/8/9/0/1 Ethernet Pro 100 (rev 0c)
07:09.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82557/8/9/0/1 Ethernet Pro 100 (rev 0c)
07:0b.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8100/8101L/8139 PCI     Fast Ethernet Adapter (rev 10)
[root@System911 ~]# lspci -k -nn | grep -i 'ethernet'
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82566DM-2 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10bd] (rev 02)
07:04.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82557/8/9/0/1 Ethernet Pro 100 [8086:1229] (rev 0c)
07:09.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82557/8/9/0/1 Ethernet Pro 100 [8086:1229] (rev 0c)
07:0b.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8100/8101L/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter [10ec:8139] (rev 10)
Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8100/8101L/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter [10ec:8139]
```

When I search for configuration files I get this:

```
[root@System911 network-scripts]# ls
ifcfg-enp0s25  ifdown-ippp    ifdown-sit       ifup-bnep  ifup-plusb   ifup-TeamPort
ifcfg-enp7s11  ifdown-ipv6    ifdown-Team      ifup-eth   ifup-post    ifup-tunnel
ifcfg-lo       ifdown-isdn    ifdown-TeamPort  ifup-ippp  ifup-ppp     ifup-wireless
ifdown         ifdown-post    ifdown-tunnel    ifup-ipv6  ifup-routes  init.ipv6-global
ifdown-bnep    ifdown-ppp     ifup             ifup-isdn  ifup-sit     network-functions
ifdown-eth     ifdown-routes  ifup-aliases     ifup-plip  ifup-Team    network-functions-ipv6
```

Comment: I believe your question needs additional information.  Just why do you say these interfaces are missing?  I see them just fine in the samples.  Are you using Network Manager (always a problem) or are did you config the interfaces directly in the interfaces file?  Did you check udev?  More info and perhaps someone could help.

Comment: Yes they are missing from network manager. What kinda information would you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I installed the operating system I found I were missing two NICs from network manager and when we used the command:

`~] #      lspci -k -nn | grep -i 'ethernet'`

I found out that we have the card installed but they were not performing the task. Both of them were of same king and it was obvious that these routers were missing drivers, I tried to search for drivers and found the drivers on elrepo and the driver name was kmod-e100. I tried installing it using:

`~] #     yum install kmod-e100`

but it didn’t work and after more research I found out that to install this driver you have to declare the repositories by using this command:

```
~] #     rpm -Uvh http://www.elrepo.org/elrepo-release-7.0-2.el7.elrepo.noarch.rpm
```

and now when I used the same yum command it worked.